# Python package setup script install binary executable

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a package `awesomepkg` with `setup.py`. I'd like to install a binary executable `awesometool` to the command line along with the package itself when users run `pip install awesomepkg`. I have compiled different OS versions for `awesometool`, which lives in a `bin/` folder beside `setup.py`.

However, I can't find a good way to configure `setup.py`. I have attempted the following:

1. Use the `scripts=[]` keyword in `setup()`. Unfortunately, the "executable" must be a python script.
2. So I try to wrap the binary in a python script using `os.system('bin/awesometool')` to delegate. It also fails because the wrapper script is copied somewhere else by pip, so it doesn't know where the relative path `bin/awesometool` is.
3. Another potential solution is the `data_files` keyword. However, for some reason the data files are not copied over to `site_packages` installation dir, even though running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` says they have been copied.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself. My solution was three-fold.

1. I added the program, e.g. `awesometool`, to my package structure so I could add it via the `package_data` keyword:
   `package_data={'awesomepkg': ['awesometool']}`.
   This causes it to actually be copied into the same folder as the main **init**.py during installation.
2. I made a python script similar to your step 2. However, instead of the relative path, I first import `awesomepkg` and use `awesomepkg.__path__` to get the absolute path to the installation folder for the package. This would look like:

   ```
   import awesomepkg
   import subprocess as sp
   import sys

   path = awesomepkg.__path__[0]
   command = path + "/awesometool"
   sp.call([command] + sys.argv)
   ```

   I also used subprocess instead of system, but the result should be the same.
3. I added this script to the `scripts` keyword of `setup()`

Comment: Shortly speaking just to sum it up, you have made a Python wrapper script and added it to the `scripts` keyworkd of `setup()`.

Comment: I ran into problem here, I get error `Permission denied` because of the ownership of the binary file. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Nick Porubsky﻿﻿'s answer:

1. Ensure the binaries have got execute flag enabled when you commit them `chmod +x`
2. Ensure you have a shebang on your bash script so it knows to execute with Python

An example of this can be found here.
https://github.com/HousekeepLtd/pywkher/commit/0bad81240f16479550e2b1bf2c1185a20d3cee29

Answer (score 0):

From **within** a package can use

```
import os
command = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "awesometool")
```