# Is it possible to make setuptool to set a binary as exectuable when installed

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have three binary executables which are compiled for OSX, Windows and Linux. Which are going to be called by a pythonscript, my problem is that the package is built on a windows machine which strips the file attributes from the binaries for OSX and Linux. What I'm looking for is a way of making setuptools set the executable attribute to the files when it copies it into the python package.

So what I have for installing the package for now is `MANIFEST.in` file containing:

```
recursive-include foo/bar/lib *%
```

which includes three folders Linux, OSX and Windows

Then the `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='foobar',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=['foo','bar'],
      entry_points='''
              [console_scripts]
              foobar=foobar.cli:cli
      ''',
      )
```

I've also used

```
package_data={
      'lib': ['lib/*'],
   },
   include_package_data=True,
```

in `setup.py` before but I moved over to manifest as I want it to work with `bdist` and `sdist`.

So what I'm looking for is to make sure that the `-x` flag is set on the binary files which are installed when calling `python install .` inside the folder. As this is not distributed as a pip package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, no way. `pip` is a rather simplistic package manager intended to install **Python** libraries and accompanying **Python** scripts.

People [try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47191379/7976758) tricks but they [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142938/python-package-setup-script-install-binary-executable#comment82652797_47191379).

You need a real package manager.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation of what I suspected :)

Comment: One question would adding `os.chmod(path_to_executable, <executable attribute>` to setup.py not work?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `os.chmod(path_to_executable, <executable attribute>` into `setup.py` worked for me at least.

Comment: Works only for sdist. Doesn't work for wheels as wheel installation doesn't use `setup.py` (it's used at packaging time).